# Function for Impulse Response Function

Tags: r, function

I created following example code to draw an "impulse response function" in R with help of the `[vars][1]` package.

```
library(vars)
data(Canada)
Canada <- data.frame(Canada)

irfplot = function(x, y) {
  VAR <- VAR(cbind(x,y), p = 2, type = "trend")
  irf_o <-irf(VAR, impulse = colnames(VAR$y)[1], response = colnames(VAR$y)[2], boot = TRUE, cumulative = FALSE, n.ahead = 20, ci = 0.90)
  plot(irf_o)
}

irfplot(Canada["rw"],Canada["U"])
```

That should work so far. However, when trying to make the script more flexible by writing the function as

```
irfplot = function(x, y, lags, deter) {
      VAR <- VAR(cbind(x,y), p = lags, type = deter)
...

irfplot(Canada["rw"],Canada["U"], 2, "trend")
```

it returns:

```
Error in VAR(y = ysampled, p = lags, type = "trend") : 
  object 'lags' not found
```

**Question:** How can the issue be resolved? I have some other functions that transfer values via objects, but for any reason, it does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems to be a scoping issue with the function because if I run `lags = 2; deter = "trend"; irfplot(Canada["rw"],Canada["U"], 2, "trend")`, it works. I.e. if `lags` and `deter` are in the global environment it works.

Comment: Yes, that is my suggestion. I only wonder how to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by global environment, related to above code?

Comment: I think it's a problem with the package that try to use non-standard evaluation. You should report the bug to the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue

The issue is the `boot = TRUE` argument to the `irf()` function. First note that, the following works just fine

```
irfplot <- function(x, y, lags, deter) {

  var_o   <- VAR(cbind(x, y), p = lags, type = deter)
  irf_o <- irf(var_o, 
               impulse = colnames(var_o$y)[1], 
               response = colnames(var_o$y)[2], boot = FALSE)
  plot(irf_o)
}
irfplot(Canada["rw"], Canada["U"], 3, "trend")
```

Changing `boot` to `TRUE` causes the error. What happens is that `lags` and `deter` apparaently do not get passed on correctly to the the function that performs bootstrapping. Although, I dont think its technically a bug, it would certainly be helpful if the author of the package changed it.

#### Solution

Whenever you want to pass on some function arguments in your top-level function to some lower level function its less error prone (as you see in your example) and generally recommended to use the `...` argument.

```
irfplot <- function(x, y, ...) {

  var_o   <- VAR(cbind(x, y), ...)
  irf_o <- irf(var_o, 
               impulse = colnames(var_o$y)[1], 
               response = colnames(var_o$y)[2], boot = TRUE)
  plot(irf_o)
}
irfplot(Canada["rw"], Canada["U"], 3, "trend")
```

Comment: ... means to have a space where any of a function's attributes can be called?

Comment: `...` is basically a placeholder for all the function arguments of the lower level function which has `...` in it as well. In your case, we put `...` as an argument in our top level function `irfplot()` and in the `VAR()` function. Now we can use all arguments of `VAR()` directly in our top level function.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [F. Privé](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6103040/f-priv%c3%a9) that you should report this as a bug to the author. However, in the interest of just solving your problem quickly, changing the argument names to match those of the `vars` function calls will work for you:

```
library(vars)
data(Canada)
Canada <- data.frame(Canada)

irfplot <- function(x, y, p, type) {
    VAR <- VAR(cbind(x,y), p=p, type=type)
    irf_o <-irf(VAR, impulse=colnames(VAR$y)[1], response=colnames(VAR$y)[2],
                boot=TRUE, cumulative=FALSE, n.ahead=20, ci=0.90)
    plot(irf_o)
}

irfplot(x=Canada["rw"], y=Canada["U"], p=2, type="trend")
```

For me, this produced the following plot:

[image: irfplot]